# iOS / macOS: How to implement Shared With You without using Universal Links?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, ios-universal-links

I'm working on an iOS and macOS app and I'm interested in implementing the `Shared With You` feature. However, I'm facing a challenge as I want to add **all** shared links to my app, similar to how Safari displays them, not just the links that are tied to my app or domain.

**Safari:**

[image: Shared With You example - Safari]

From my understanding, the `Shared With You` feature is typically implemented using Universal Links. But in my case, I want to handle all types of URLs, not just the ones associated with my app.  Is there a way to implement this without using Universal Links or to specify a wildcat for Universal Links?

It looks like this is possible as Apple is doing it in Safari on macOS and iOS, but maybe they have restricted this to their apps.